# I am trying python with selenium using pycharm and getting the error step_impl() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'

Tags: python, selenium

Here is the code for reference

```
@then('I search for keyword Diksha')
def step_impl(context):
    element = context.browser.find_by_id(context,'lst-ib','Diksha')

from selenium import webdriver
from webbrowser import browser

class Browser(object):

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('H:\\Desktop\\KEPLER\\Browser Drivers\\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    def find_by_id(self, selector,text):
        object = self.driver.find_element_by_id(selector).send_keys(text)
        return object

    def before_all(context):
        context.driver = webdriver.Chrome("H:\\Desktop\\KEPLER\\Browser Drivers\\chromedriver.exe")
        driver = context.driver

    def after_all(context):
        context.browser.quit()
```

Error:

Here's the full error description

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.3.2\helpers\pycharm\nose_helper\case.py", line 68, in runTest self.test(*self.arg)
TypeError: step_impl() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'
```

Comment: edit that into the question

Comment: and format it please

Comment: Did that , formatted it